# More than 1 result of sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have sql query

```
SELECT RV.duration, 
       P.expirytime 
FROM   rid_purchase_info_v64 AS P 
       INNER JOIN rid_video_asset_movievod AS RV 
               ON RV.rid = P.rid 
WHERE  RV.rid = 31041;
```

I am getting result

`7166|1386308217`

`143|1386308217`
Why am I getting 2 results instead of 1

Comment: Please post (a) the CREATE TABLE statements and (b) the INSERT INTO ... VALUES statements required to reproduce your results. Otherwise, it will be hard for people to help you.

Comment: can you able make sqlfiddle

Comment: Why do you expect getting only one result when you have two matching rows?

Comment: execute select * from rid_video_asset_movievod where id=31041 and check how many values you getting

Comment: So, what should be the expected output look like?

Comment: @Suganthan I am getting 2 results having .I understood it I have to put one more attribute in where statement.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the table rid_purchase_info_v64 is in one to many relationship with rid_video_asset_movievod table. There are more than one entries in RV related to P. Many developers put an attribute 'deleted' or 'status=disable' to hide the unwanted row.

What you need to do is identify such attribute and put in where statement. This is very common problem with beginners.

Comment: Exactly.When I do `select * from rid_video_asset_movievod where rid=31041` I get 2 different results having different no of rows each.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only 1 row then try to use LIMIT, like:

```
 SELECT RV.duration, 
   P.expirytime 
 FROM   rid_purchase_info_v64 AS P 
   INNER JOIN rid_video_asset_movievod AS RV 
           ON RV.rid = P.rid 
 WHERE RV.rid = 31041
 LIMIT 1
```

Or if you want to get the highest value you could use an Aggregate function MAX():

```
 SELECT MAX(RV.duration),
   P.expirytime 
 FROM   rid_purchase_info_v64 AS P 
 INNER JOIN rid_video_asset_movievod AS RV 
           ON RV.rid = P.rid 
 WHERE RV.rid = 31041
 GROUP BY P.expirytime
```

Or for smallest value MIN():

```
 SELECT MIN(RV.duration),
   P.expirytime 
 FROM   rid_purchase_info_v64 AS P 
 INNER JOIN rid_video_asset_movievod AS RV 
           ON RV.rid = P.rid 
 WHERE RV.rid = 31041
 GROUP BY P.expirytime
```

Comment: ... while this will result in only one row, this may only mask a deeper problem.  Depending on the data in the tables and the intended use of the query, this might whitewash something that should be breaking.

Comment: For `LIMIT 1` you're right @Clockwork-Muse. But for `MAX()` or `MIN()` if he wants to find only either the highest or lowest value respectively that would not be a problem.

Comment: No, I'm counting the `MAX()` and `MIN()` (and all other aggregate functions) in the same boat.  If he should be getting only one result, period, they could still be masking the problem.  This depends heavily on what the OP is attempting to accomplish, so it may be valid; however, blindly using these functions for 'deduping' will likely cause some surprises later down the road.